# Java: Stream Contents of Zipfile via HTTP

Tags: java, http, streaming, zip

I have quite some amount of streamable data (>100MB), which, for the sake of compression, i would like to host packed in a zipfile on an http-server. So this zipfile contains a single file.

Now is it possible for a java-client to stream the data via http, even though it is packed in a zipfile?

According to wikipedia, ZIPs are not sequentially...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Structure

If this is still possible somehow, then how?

edit: about gzip: as i said, i use a custom java client (not a webbrowser) is gzip available in the java http implementation?

Comment: You're talking about streaming the files inside the zip file individually, not the whole zip file right?

Comment: well actually the zipfile contains just one file. and this is the one i want to stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java supports the `gzip` format with the `GZipInputStream` (decompressing) and `GZipOutputStream` (compressing). Both `zip` and `gzip` use the same compressing format internally, the main difference is in the metadata: `zip` has it at the end of the file, `gzip` at the beginning (and `gzip` only supports one enclosed file easily).

For your of streaming one big file, using `gzip` will be the better thing to do - even more as you don't need access to the metadata.

I'm not sure if the HTTPConnection sends `Accept-Encoding: gzip` and then handles inflating the content automatically if the server delivers it with `Content-Encoding: gzip`, but you surely can do it manually if the server simply sends a the `.gz` file as such (i.e. with `Content-Encoding: identity`).

(By the way, make sure to read from the stream with not too small buffers, as each deflate call will have a native call overhead, since Java's GZipInputStream uses the native **zlib** implementation.)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a snippet of code (that works) that the client can use to read from the zipped stream:

```
static void processZippedInputStream(InputStream in, String entryNameRegex)
throws IOException
{
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
    ZipEntry ze;
    while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        if (ze.getName().matches(entryNameRegex))
        {
            // treat zin as a normal input stream - ie read() from it till "empty" etc
            break;
        }
        zin.closeEntry();
    }
    zin.close();
}
```

The main difference with a normal InputStream is iterating through the entries. You may know, for example, that you want the first entry, so no need for the name matching parameter etc.

Comment: as i said, the zipfile would only contain one single entry. unforutnately it seems that the metainformation about this is at the very end of the zipfile, so i would need to download the whole file before i can start to unzip, right?

Comment: No - the entries are encountered by name then contents, so you'll get the entry header right up front

Answer (score 5):

Would it make more sense to let the web server do the zipping?  If you are simply trying to reduce the amount of bandwidth being used, rather than really wanting to store the file zipped up on the server, this would simply be a matter of configurations, for example see:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

for HTTP/1.1 GZIP compression.  The server can force the response to the client to be zipped.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression.

The client will receive zipped packets and handle the unzipping.  It should be possible to stream the file too, so the client doesn't need all the file before it can do something useful, because the server can zip individual chunks.

Comment: I agree with @Ant's basic point--if you've got a single file, use straight compression rather than a zip archive.  The file can be compressed or not on the server, as you like.

Comment: you have not got the problem here. If you zip the file, then to unzip at the other end, you need the entire zip file. So you can't make any use of the data inside the zip if its partially there on the client. So basically even though the zip file itself is getting streamed, the audio itself is not. I believe the solution is to use low-bit rate or better streaming formats

Comment: @Suraj if the individual chunks are zipped, then no, you dont have the problem.  but its true that you need to check what happens if you used Transfer-Encoding chunked together with GZIP compression.  potentially, you need to use just chunked transfer encoding, and zip the chunks yourself and unzip them on the client, which is messy!  i dont really know exactly how it works without trying it, but i assume individual chunks will be gzipped.  if anyone tries it, let me know!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip - seems to suggest gzip uses a stream, ie you dont need the entire thing to start unzipping... so i imagine it works. try it and see :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, Stream the zip and use the MIME type as **application/zip**

If you actually want to play stream music on the other end, then it can't be done trivially as you can only unpack once the entire zip is available on client.

If size is you concern, you can either turn down your mp3 bit-rate or use formats such as ogg/vorbis

Comment: are you sure, because this image says it is not streamable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ZIPformat.jpg

Comment: @clamp: You can stream it, but you can't unpack it until you receive the entire contents of the file on the client side. (that's what the image/article is describing)

Comment: well ok, but this is actually what i want. the contents of the file is what i want to stream.

Comment: @clamp why not use a lower bit rate or a low-size like ogg

Comment: @suraj, this is not an audiofile, it is a custom data.

Comment: so is the custom data useable in a partial form in the client side? what forma tis this data

Answer (score 0):

Use GZIP and then you can stream. Gzip uses the default compression algorithm of zip anyway.

Comment: thanks, but is this gzip available in the java http implementation?

Comment: sure just send a gzipstream and on the server side store the stream to disk. You just wrap the current streams. The gzipstream is the enclosed entity inside the POST or PUT