# php: Is it possible to extract a zip file from a URL without writing the zip to disk?

Tags: php, url, zip, extract, unzip

I'm grabbing the zip file from a URL, then I copy the zip onto disk only to grab it from disk and extract it. I want to eliminate the step of having to write the zip to disk to optimize it. Here is my code...

```
$url_zip = 'http://returns_my_zip_file';
$new_file = '/zip_name.zip';
if (!copy($url_zip, $new_file)) { //<--- I want to eliminate this step.
    echo "\n\nFailed to copy file...\n\n";
}

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if(is_readable($new_file)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($new_file) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('ExtractToThisFolder');
        $zip->close();
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225488/java-stream-contents-of-zipfile-via-http, `zip` files have their metadata at the end and therefore they cannot be streamed easily.

Comment: Like Jake said, you most likely can not, but you might be able to do something like write it to php://memory instead of disk. Depends on your server and setup. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Was just looking at that Jon, thanks!